# Qlik Sense - Data Table Associations without using the Data Manager

Tags: file-association

Currently I am using Qlik Sense for a big data project. Inside QlikSense there is a section in which a user can associate qvd files. Due to the volume of data, the association fails. Does anyone know an alternative to Data Manager (i.e. Data Load Editor) in which you can associate qvd files via script and not by the Data Manager?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you load data in a Qlik Sense application, a script is executed to do the lifting and creating of the relational database that Qlik operates on top of. While the Data Manager is a user-friendly way of automatically generating a data loading script, the Data Load Editor **is** editing the script directly.

> Note: If you know some programming, the script is SQL-like in syntax but with their own library of additional functions.

Getting started on the Data Load Editor: https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/June2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/introduction-data-modeling.htm

---

In Qlik's user-friendly Data Manager, when you select the bubbles to associate data, Qlik Sense is creating synthetic keys that match in name so that a link is made between the data sets.

When you edit the data loading script itself, you **do not need to dictate associations**. Data that shares the same name **will** be linked together, because that is how SQL (Structured Query Language) operates and is the same thing as a Qlik association.

## Script Example

This is a quick example of what our script would look like. This data would be "associated" via ShiftID in the eyes of the Data Manager, but because they're the same name in our relational database, that links them together.

```
[Employees]:
LOAD
  ID,
  ShiftID,
  FirstName as "First",
  LastName as "Last"
FROM [lib://Data.csv]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is [EmployeesNovember2019]);

[Shift]:
LOAD
  ShiftID,
  Schedule
FROM [lib://Schedule.csv]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is [ScheduleNovember2019]);
```

## For Future Reference

For timeliness in response in your future Qlik adventure, I would highly recommend checking out Stack Overflow or the very populated Qlik Community Forum.

Qlik Community Forum: https://community.qlik.com/

---

Hope this helps, and good luck!